# how do I check if a repo was cloned via `--single-branch` option?

Tags: git

`git rev-parse` has an option `--is-shallow-repository` to check if a sandbox is a shallow clone. However, I would like to check if the repository was cloned by `--single-branch`.

I know it is possible to parse the `git config remote.origin.fetch` result by myself. However, this is quite annoying and I do not know how stable the fetch value is. I would like to know if there a canonical way to determine this.

Comment: Parsing the output of `git config remote.origin.fetch` is a non-precise heuristics. But I'm afraid it's the only way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A clone could switch from being a single-branch clone to being a multi- or all-branch clone (using `git remote set-branches`), or vice versa; in this case, the *initial* state is lost and only the *current* state is available.  So it's not possible to find out what the state was at the time the repository was cloned.  But usually that's not very interesting: what you want to know is the state *right now*, for which your `git config --get-all remote.origin.fetch` is probably the right answer.  If this outputs more than one line, you have a multi-branch (but perhaps not full) clone; if it outputs a single line, and the single line matches the default, you have a standard clone; otherwise you have a single or multi-branch clone, probably not full.

(This assumes the remote name is `origin`; substitute in the correct name as necessary.)

(Note that this is the same as the `--is-shallow-repository` test, which tests the *current* state, not the initial clone state, in case you have run `git fetch --unshallow`.)